# JQ Grid Search for children as well when searching for Paren

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I am fairly new to JQ Grid and I am using the Adjacency model for displaying the Hierarchical structure. The Requirement is such that,  when I search for a text and if It happens to have child nodes, I want to display those child nodes as well in the search results.In the demos I see that, when I search for a Leaf Node, all its parents are listed in the search result, but when I search for a parent its children are not listed in the results.
I believe this is not available out of the box for JQ grid plugin , any help or pointers to the solution are highly Appreciable.

example - Say I have data like below,

- ELECTRONICS

  - TELEVISIONS

    - TUBE

      - 26 " TV
      - 30 " TV

So say, if I search for Electronics , my search result should include all its children which in this case are Televisions,Tube, and both the leaf nodes and not just Electronics.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov I am using - Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.4.0

Comment: I see the issue you describe. I will see what I can do.